# How to select the greatest timestamp in a subquery

Tags: sql

I have two tables, one with equipment and another that keeps a log of each equipment's status (IN or OUT) and the time of the change. I am trying to make a query that will give me the last known status of every piece of equipment. The query I've come up with forces me to group by status which shows both check IN and check OUT records. I can't figure out how to get this working properly. Any help would be appreciated

```
SELECT a.[assetid], a.[name], a.[manufacturer], a.[type], b.[status], b.[timestamp]
FROM .[dbo].[equipment] a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT assetid, status, MAX(timestamp) as timestamp FROM [dbo].[log] GROUP BY assetid, status) b ON a.assetid=b.assetid
```

Results:

[image: http://i57.tinypic.com/5mhjiv.png]

Desired Results:

[image: http://i57.tinypic.com/apjp74.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you need to `group by status` in your subquery, just `assetid` should be fine. Also change the join to `inner join` and add an condition on the `timestamp`.

Try this ...

```
 SELECT a.[assetid], a.[name], a.[manufacturer], a.[type], b.[status], b.[timestamp]
    FROM .[dbo].[equipment] a
    left JOIN 
    (SELECT assetid, status, timestamp FROM [dbo].[log] l
     inner join 
     (SELECT assetid, MAX(timestamp) as timestamp FROM [dbo].[log] GROUP BY assetid) k
         on l.assetid=k.assetid and l.timestamp=k.timestamp) b 
ON a.assetid=b.assetid
```

Comment: You have to select Status from the subquery in order to return it - it does not exist in the equipment table. Additionally, timestamp is only in the log table. I want a left join because I want all equipment listed regardless if a status and timestamp has been recorded